# How can I add my Android App to Share Dialog?

Tags: android, list, listener, share

I want to add my App to "Share via" Dialog. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an intent filter to the manifest file, specifying an action and mime type your application should handle. Something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think it's `text/x-vcalendar` though I am not sure as have never tried it myself. Let know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the appropriate Intent filter to your Activity. Should be this one if I'm not wrong:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
```